# Input Dimensionality for an LSTM in Keras

Tags: input, keras, reshape, lstm

So I'm pretty sure I'm inputting the dimensions correctly. I think the error lies in the reshape of the input, but not really sure.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
df_matrix = df_model.as_matrix()
df_matrix = np.reshape(df_matrix,(-1,588425,26))
df_matrix.shape
y_matrix = y.as_matrix()
y_matrix = np.reshape(y_matrix,(-1,588425,1))
df_matrix2 = df_model.as_matrix()

model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(588425, 26), return_sequences = True))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(df_matrix2, y, epochs=2, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Which is popping out this error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_17: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

The output for df_matrix2.shape is (588425, 26). I also tried df_matrix which I reshaped into a 3D array and the output for df_matrix is (1, 588425, 26). Both failed, so I'm unsure what the problem in the input space is? Since both a 2-d and 3-d input gave me the same error.

Comment: Do you have 588K sequences of length 26 with 1 feature or 1 sequence with 588K time steps and 26 features?

Comment: I have 1 sequence with 588k time steps and 26 features per time step

Comment: What's the error after reshaping to `(1, ...)`?

Comment: Same exact error

Comment: Could you print out `df_matrix2.shape`?

Comment: df_matrix2.shape =(588425, 26)

Comment: I also tried df_matrix within the model. df_matrix.shape = (1, 588425, 26)  both kick off the same error

Comment: try: `df_matrix2 = np.reshape(df_matrix.as_matrix(), (-1,588425,26))`

Comment: Well I actually just tried it again, and saw that with the 3 dimensional input array it moved past the initial part, but then had an error checking the target which was a 3-d array, since it was looking for something that was 1,588425,32), when the target array was just (1,588425,1). So I tried flattening and adding a Dense(1) layer to the model to get that, and then it starting kicking off the same input 0 error as above again. I may actually have an internal model issue??

Comment: Could you print out `y_shape`? I don`t think it`s inner model error. It's shape error - you cannot reshape `pandas` arrays.

Comment: y.shape = (588425,), i also tried y_matrix.shape = (1, 588425, 1)

Comment: But you cannot simply set shape. You need to use `reshape` function. Try `y = np.reshape(y.as_matrix(), (-1,588425,1))`

Comment: I may not have included but I did that above df_matrix = 
    df_model.as_matrix()
    df_matrix = np.reshape(df_matrix,(-1,588425,26))
    df_matrix.shape
    y_matrix = y.as_matrix()
    y_matrix = np.reshape(y_matrix,(-1,588425,1))
    df_matrix2 = df_model.as_matrix()
    y_matrix.shape

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153483/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-a1letterword).

Answer (score 1):

the answer for your question is already in your question:

> Which is popping out this error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_17: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

So, what should you do?

You have an input list which has shape like this:

```
(N,N)
```

But, for LSTMs you need shape:

```
(N,N,N)
```

The simples solution would be to make something like this:

```
y_matrix = np.reshape(y_matrix,(588425,1,1))
```

Also, don't forget to change the number in your NN:

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences = True))
```